# I'm trying to install game with wine but when i try to open launcher it gives an error

Tags: apt, wine, launcher, games

I tried i386 structure, Windows compatibility 7+ and many more but it gives an error when opened.

[image: Program Error]

And also i can't run this command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

But when i try it gives an error "The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

> ```
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details."
> ```

Also i have game program error details:

> ```
> Modules:
> Module  Address         Debug info  Name (50 modules)
> PE    400000-  559000   Deferred        launcher
> PE  10000000-12f89000   Export          libcef
> PE  7ac10000-7ac23000   Deferred        riched20
> PE  7b410000-7b5b6000   Deferred        kernel32
> PE  7bc10000-7bc14000   Deferred        ntdll
> PE  7d680000-7d683000   Deferred        winejoystick
> PE  7d6a0000-7d6ae000   Deferred        setupapi
> PE  7da10000-7da14000   Deferred        dwmapi
> PE  7da30000-7da33000   Deferred        dwrite
> PE  7da90000-7da94000   Deferred        bcrypt
> PE  7dab0000-7dab4000   Deferred        rsaenh
> PE  7e540000-7e544000   Deferred        msftedit
> PE  7e560000-7e564000   Deferred        iphlpapi
> PE  7e590000-7e593000   Deferred        netapi32
> PE  7e5b0000-7e5b3000   Deferred        secur32
> PE  7e5f0000-7e606000   Deferred        oleacc
> PE  7e650000-7e653000   Deferred        dhcpcsvc
> PE  7e660000-7e671000   Deferred        urlmon
> PE  7e700000-7e703000   Deferred        userenv
> PE  7e710000-7e715000   Deferred        jsproxy
> PE  7e730000-7e736000   Deferred        winhttp
> PE  7e770000-7e809000   Deferred        comdlg32
> PE  7e860000-7e86a000   Deferred        winspool
> PE  7e8a0000-7e8a4000   Deferred        psapi
> PE  7e8b0000-7e8b3000   Deferred        usp10
> PE  7e8f0000-7e8f3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
> PE  7e900000-7e903000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1.dll
> PE  7e920000-7e923000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
> PE  7eb40000-7eb43000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
> PE  7eb60000-7eb64000   Deferred        winex11
> PE  7ebe0000-7ebe4000   Deferred        imm32
> PE  7edc0000-7edc4000   Deferred        ws2_32
> PE  7ee00000-7ee0a000   Deferred        mpr
> PE  7ee60000-7ee78000   Deferred        wininet
> PE  7eee0000-7eee3000   Deferred        wtsapi32
> PE  7eef0000-7eef4000   Deferred        uxtheme
> PE  7ef30000-7ef33000   Deferred        msimg32
> PE  7ef40000-7ef81000   Deferred        crypt32
> PE  7f010000-7f060000   Deferred        comctl32
> PE  7f130000-7f139000   Deferred        msacm32
> PE  7f150000-7f1c8000   Deferred        winmm
> PE  7f220000-7f2b2000   Deferred        oleaut32
> PE  7f340000-7f344000   Deferred        rpcrt4
> PE  7f3d0000-7f3f8000   Deferred        ole32
> PE  7f520000-7f528000   Deferred        shlwapi
> PE  7f5a0000-7f702000   Deferred        shell32
> PE  7f7f0000-7f7f4000   Deferred        advapi32
> PE  7f860000-7f867000   Deferred        gdi32
> PE  7f990000-7fa56000   Deferred        user32
> PE  7fba0000-7fba4000   Deferred        version
> Threads:
> process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
> 0000000e services.exe
>     00000022    0
>     0000001d    0
>     00000013    0
>     00000010    0
>     0000000f    0
> 00000011 winedevice.exe
>     0000001c    0
>     00000017    0
>     00000016    0
>     00000012    0
> 0000001a plugplay.exe
>     0000001f    0
>     0000001e    0
>     0000001b    0
> 00000020 winedevice.exe
>     00000029    0
>     00000024    0
>     00000023    0
>     00000021    0
> 00000027 explorer.exe
>     0000002c    0
>     0000002b    0
>     0000002a    0
>     00000028    0
> 0000002d Steam.exe
>     0000013f    0
>     00000095    0
>     00000094    0
>     0000006b    0
>     00000067    0
>     00000066    0
>     00000063    0
>     00000062    0
>     0000005f    0
>     0000005e    0
>     0000005b    0
>     0000005a    0
>     00000059    0
>     00000058    0
>     00000057    0
>     00000056    0
>     00000055    0
>     00000053    2
>     00000052    2
>     0000004f    0
>     0000004d    0
>     0000004c    0
>     00000037    0
>     00000036    0
>     00000035    0
>     00000034    0
>     00000031    0
>     00000030    0
>     0000002f    0
>     0000002e    0
> 00000032 steamwebhelper.exe
>     0000006a    0
>     0000004b    0
>     0000004a    0
>     00000049    0
>     00000048    0
>     00000047    0
>     00000046    0
>     00000045    0
>     00000044    0
>     00000043    0
>     00000042    0
>     00000041    0
>     00000040    0
>     0000003f    0
>     0000003e    0
>     0000003d    0
>     0000003c    0
>     0000003b    0
>     0000003a    0
>     00000039    0
>     00000038    0
>     00000033    0
> 0000019e (D) C:\users\george\Local Settings\Application Data\Warframe\Downloaded\Public\Tools\Launcher.exe
>     000001ba    0
>     000001b9    0
>     000001b8    0
>     000001b7    0
>     000001b4    0
>     000001b3    0
>     000001b2    0
>     000001b1    0
>     000001b0    0
>     000001af    0
>     000001ae    0
>     000001ad    0
>     000001ac    0 <==
>     000001ab    0
>     000001aa    0
>     000001a9    0
>     000001a8    0
>     000001a7    0
>     000001a6    0
>     000001a5    0
>     000001a4    0
>     000001a3    0
>     000001a2    0
>     000001a1    0
>     000001a0    0
>     0000019f    0
> System information:
>     Wine build: wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1)
>     Platform: i386 (WOW64)
>     Version: Windows 7
>     Host system: Linux
>     Host version: 4.18.0-16-generic
> ```

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

This ppa is obsolete according [here](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2017-March/117104.html) to add the proper one according the announcement in the mailing list you should:

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
```